# Android Schedule Task events view

Tags: android

I am new to android development, how to add events using list view and how to change the background. To be more specific, i want to develop below screen:

[image]

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated...

Comment: I am try to attached but it is giving me error. just let me know how to do it..

Comment: It say u need atleast 10 reputation to attached screen.

Comment: So you can display the image now...

Comment: please find the image attached..